# Gradle Build Exception : AAPT process not ready to receive commands

Tags: android

This might be duplicate question but after trying all solution I'm not able to solve following error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: AAPT process not ready to receive commands
```

I tried all except one solution:

```
sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6
sudo apt-get install lib32z1
```

what exactly commands will be before executing this commands?? and if anyone have other solution than this please tell me, It will be very useful..

Comment: jdk path is correct and i have tried downgrading gradle but still have same error.

Answer (score 5):

linux 64ver, install

- **lib32stdc++6**(or **lib32stdc++5**)
- **lib32z1**(maybe its name is **lib32zlib**)

you can search them here ,to confirm their real names in you linux distro repo. https://pkgs.org/

Answer (score 1):

Go to Project structure by clicking `(ctrl+shift+alt+s)`, in that go to `Project` tab change `Gradle Version` to `3.2` and `Project Version` to `2.2` .

This works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple . 
inside the gradle  module app change the build tool version to 23.0.3 , gradle version to 2.2.2