# Android studio 2.3.3 error

Tags: android, android-studio-2.3

I am using 32 bit ubuntu. I recently updated android studio to 2.3.3. Now, Whenever I create a project Android Studio give the following error :

> Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: AAPT process not ready to receive commands
>       Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
>
> Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: AAPT process not ready to receive commands

What is the solution?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43916513/gradle-build-exception-aapt-process-not-ready-to-receive-commands

Comment: Did you try to clean and rebuild your project ?

Comment: Done clean & rebuild. Still error occurs.