# the first time I run 'react-native run-android', I got this error:

Tags: android, react-native, aapt

This is the error log:

```
 Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: **AAPT process not ready to receive commands**
    :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED
```

Answer (score 2):

#### when I run this command : `$ aapt` it responsed me that:

```
aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

#### and then I run :  `$ locate libz.so`, it responsed me that:

```
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.8
```

#### at this moment, I was so confused that there's nothing wrong, so I run `$ aapt --help` again, but it also returned me that :

```
aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

#### at last, I got it solved at [this place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43916513/gradle-build-exception-aapt-process-not-ready-to-receive-commands), with this `$ sudo apt-get install lib32z1` command, installing the *lib32z1.so* file, and now it works very well!

Answer (score 0):

React-native does not offer full error information. The most straightforward way is to open the Android project under "ProjectFolder\Android" and build the project in **AndroidStudio**, where much richer info can be found.

For even more details, you can use **"--stacktrace --debug"** command line options,  follow below procedures:

- Open AndroidStudio
- Preferences > Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler
- Add "--stacktrace --debug" to the commandline as shown in below snapshot
- Rebuild in AndroidStudio, more detailed information will be shown

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My problem, on Linux, was the path:

I export ANDROID_HOME with *.bash_profile* but I forgive to reload it in my terminal with `. ~/.bash_profile` before open android studio.

**Step by step:**

1. Close Android Studio.
2. Reload bash profile `. ~/.bash_profile` or export path:

   `export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Android/Sdk
   export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
   export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools`
3. Open Android Studio.
4. Run device. I try with a Nexus 4 but it doesn't matters. Use API 23 X86_64 (Google APIs) like tutorial says.
5. Go to your project in terminal and execute `react-native run-android`.

It works!!