# AAPT process not ready to recieve command Android Studio 32 bit

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, aapt

I'm running android studio on 32 bit ubuntu 16.04, and I'm trying to run my application.

When I run gradlew it works fine for me, but when I'm ready to build the apk and run it on my device, it shows my everytime:

[image: Error description]

My gradle (app) file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
  }
 dependencies {
classpath(
        'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3',
    "com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8",
)
}
}

apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply plugin: "com.neenbedankt.android-apt"

repositories {
  jcenter()
}

android {
  compileSdkVersion 17
  buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
  defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.clarifai.android.starter.api.v2"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 17
    versionCode 2
    versionName "1.1"
  }
  lintOptions { lintConfig rootProject.file('gradle/lint.xml') } // needed              to suppress Okio's lint errors
}

dependencies {
  compile(
          "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1",
          "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.1",
          "com.android.support:design:24.2.1",

          "com.clarifai.clarifai-api2:core:2.2.+",

          // For logging our HTTP outbound + inbound data
          "com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.3.0",
          "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.1",

          // For runtime permissions on Marshmallow and above
          "io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.10",
          "com.tbruyelle.rxpermissions:rxpermissions:0.7.1@aar",
  )
  compile('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:5.6.0') { transitive = true }
  // For getting views without clunky findViewById
  compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'
  apt "com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0"
}
```

(sorry for the bad indents)

Please help me understand what the problem is.

I was trying all the suggestions in the net so far to my problem, but none helped.

Comment: Might be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43916513/gradle-build-exception-aapt-process-not-ready-to-receive-commands

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gradle Build Exception : AAPT process not ready to receive commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43916513/gradle-build-exception-aapt-process-not-ready-to-receive-commands)